# How to configure yarn workspaces

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, yarnpkg, mobx, yarn-workspaces

I configured our new project using yarn workspaces as below

```
MyProject
  - native
  - shared
  - web
```

`shared` is a dependency for both `native` and `web`. As we're using mobx and decorators, I configured `transform-decorators-legacy` in `.babelrc` of both `shared` and `web` folders. Now I'm trying to run `npm start` in `web` and getting build errors.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'
```

I think we have to babelify the `shared` folder. So did any one face this kind of issue? How we have to configure the project?

Comment: I think this is the same problem I just had, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53449456/786644